# Getting FastAPI background tasks to run in ECS task

Tags: fastapi, amazon-ecs

I have a fastapi app that has the following endpoint:

```
@app.post("/endpoint")
async def process(body: Body, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    logger.info("Gets here, verified by logging statement.")

    background_tasks.add_task(some_task)

    logger.info("Gets here, verified by logging statement.")
    return {"status": 200}
```

I deployed this using AWS ECS, and I have the cluster and service up and running. I can POST to this endpoint and I get the response back, but the background task never runs. The reason I believe the background task is not running is because I have log statements within the background task that I never see in the task logs (the only logs I see are the ones in this `process()` function, not ones in the background task).

When I run the docker image locally (with `docker compose up`), the background task DOES run. What's going on here? Any help appreciated!

I tried running the same image locally, and it does run the background task. I have tried restarting the ECS service and it still did not run the background task.

Comment: If it works locally then it should work the same on ECS. I would try comparing your local container configuration with the ECS task definition, for example the `CMD` and/or `ENTRYPOINT` settings in each environment.